Replacement for deprecated asyncio.get_event_loop()
A script I am upgrading uses asyncio.get_event_loop(), which is deprecated since Python 3.12.
Asyncio documentation recommends using asyncio.get_running_loop(), which is considered more stable because its output is simpler and more predictable. However, get_running_loop() requires that the loop be running, and can only be called from a coroutine or callback - which is not compatible with my function structure.
Is there another asyncio replacement to get the event loop?

Providing more details on what your function is doing with the event loop obtained through get_event_loop() would probably help.

Usually one will want to call just asyncio.run - to get the asynchronous part of a program started in the current thread.
If one needs a reference to the loop before calling run (in order, for example, to create futures and tasks from the synchronous code), it is possible to call asyncio.new_event_loop(), followed by loop.run_until_complete()  - in the same pattern that was used with .get_event_loop() before asyncio.run existed.
TL;DR: asyncio.new_event_loop() is the function you are looking for.

In case it's not obvious: new_event_loop() should probably be called only once, and the result stored somewhere and reused. If the script calls get_event_loop() is multiple places, one almost certainly can't go ahead and replace them all with new_event_loop().
